# Which Spark operation returns the elements not matched by a join?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I assume a Spark join is an inner join by default.

Which operation do I use to find the elements not matched by the join?

e.g. here I am trying to get rid of `edges` that are of length zero.

```
val zeroLengthNodePairs: RDD[(Node, Node)] = edges.filter(_.distance == 0)
  .map{e =>
    val List(remove, keep) = List(e.startNode, e.endNode).sortBy(_.id)
    remove -> keep
  }.distinct()

val edgesByEndNode: RDD[(Node, Edge)] = edges.map(e => e.endNode -> e)
val edgesByStartNode: RDD[(Node, Edge)] = edges.map(e => e.startNode -> e)

edgesByEndNode.join(zeroLengthNodePairs).map { case (remove, (edge, keep)) =>
  assert(edge.endNode.point == keep.point)
  edge.copy(endNode = keep)
} ++
edgesByStartNode.join(zeroLengthNodePairs).map { case (remove, (edge, keep)) =>
  assert(edge.startNode.point == keep.point)
  edge.copy(startNode = keep)
} ++
???
```

In place of the `???`, how can I add the modified `RDD[Edge]`s back with the original `edges` without including the edges before modification?

Edit: I'm thinking I should use an outerJoin. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `join` , you can do `fullOutterJoin`, and filter the values that are `None` on Either side

from the documentation:

```
def fullOuterJoin[W](other: RDD[(K, W)], numPartitions: Int): RDD[(K, (Option[V], Option[W]))]
Perform a full outer join of this and other. For each element (k, v) in this, the resulting RDD will either contain all pairs (k, (Some(v), Some(w))) for w in other, or the pair (k, (Some(v), None)) 
if no elements in other have key k. Similarly, for each element (k, w) in other, the resulting RDD will either contain all pairs (k, (Some(v), Some(w))) for v in this, or the pair (k, (None, Some(w))) if no elements in this have key k. Hash-partitions the resulting RDD into the given number of partitions.
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

Answer (score 2):

Oops. Seems there are methods in the API docs that aren't in the main Spark doco. That helps a bit!

I ended up using `subtractByKey`:

```
val modified: RDD[(Long, Edge)] = edgesByEndNode.join(zeroLengthNodePairs).map { case (remove, (edge, keep)) =>
  assert(edge.endNode.point == keep.point)
  edge.id -> edge.copy(endNode = keep)
} ++ edgesByStartNode.join(zeroLengthNodePairs).map { case (remove, (edge, keep)) =>
  assert(edge.startNode.point == keep.point)
  edge.id -> edge.copy(startNode = keep)
}

(edges.map(e => e.id -> e).subtractByKey(modified) ++ modified).values
```

Comment: Is the following [scaladoc of subtractByKey](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) you're looking for?